# Identifying coordinate system of San Francisco data?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states

I just found a [dataset of trees in San Francisco](http://www.datasf.org/story.php?title=street-tree-list), but I'm unable to determine the system used for the coordinates. Here are some samples:

```
5998894.045593,2119007.035323
6018697.2048701001,2097076.1109207
```

Does this look familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 11):

This was down a bit in the comments at the link you provided:

> SF uses State Plane, NAD 83, Zone 3, US Survey Feet. This coordinate system is used vs lat/longs as they have greater accuracy for smaller areas. We are looking at ways to convert this to lat/long to make it easier for consumers to use.